# Is the Bangalore skin "Kingslayer" a reference to Game of Thrones?

Tags: game-of-thrones, apex-legends

In the game *Apex Legends* by EA the character Bangalore has a skin called "Kingslayer". This seems like an obvious reference to Jaime Lannister from *A Song of Ice and Fire*/*Game of Thrones*, though I'm sure it is more likely a reference to the show than the books.

This seems even more likely when we look at the outfit. It is red, House Lannister's main colour, with hints of gold and the Lannister's are known to be extremely wealthy.

[image: Bangalore's Kingslayer outfit]

The Lannister armour doesn't really match though as we can see in the below picture of Jaime wearing his version of it but it is *somewhat similar* to Jaime's doublet he uses when training with Bronn, again see the image below.

[image: Jaime in his Lannister armour] [image: Jaime in his doublet]
<sub>*Click images to expand.*</sub>

Is there any official word from the game's creators that this is indeed a reference to *Game of Thrones*? I am **not** looking for speculation on this, informed or otherwise.

---

After posting this I have also noticed another Bangalore skin named "Dire wolf" which is an arctic camo. The direwolf is the sigil of House Stark who live in the North in a more "wintery" area of Westeros so again this seems like a reference.

[image: Bangalore's Dire wolf outfit]

Comment: Looking a bit further there appear to be other references hid in the skins. Caustic has a [Philosopher's Stone](https://gameguidehq.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Caustic4.png) skin with would appear to be a _Harry Potter_ reference and Gibraltar has [Dark Side](https://gameguidehq.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Gibraltar11.png) and [Millenium Tusk](https://gameguidehq.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Gibraltar10.png) ones that are probably _Star Wars_ references.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/apexlegends/comments/apjpej/bangalore_got_reference/

Comment: @Randal'Thor Aye had seen that, there is [another one](https://www.reddit.com/r/apexlegends/comments/aruj4v/bangalores_kingslayer_and_direwolf_skins_pretty/) too.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Kingslayer  It could be any kind of crap really